# What does the "Developer" option in iOS Settings app do?

Tags: ios, settings

I've had this on my iPhone every time I run my app from Xcode for the past 2 years. I don't know what it does and can't really find any information on what it does. Can anybody explain to me what it exactly does?

Answer (score 0):

They allow you to control the environment in which your apps run:

> Every developer wants to test his app against all kinds of situations so the app has the correct behaviour. Sometimes this is difficult to test, f.e. testing of an app on slower connections. This is where the iOS Developer Settings can bring you a solution.
>   These settings consist of the next topics:
>
> - Energy Diagnostic
> - Network Link conditioner
> - iAd Developer App Testing
> - PassKit Testing
> - Etc
>
> Using the Energy Diagnostic option, you can measure the energy usage in your application.
>   With the Network Link conditioner you can test how your app reacts on slower connections. Going from Wifi to 3g to edge and even slower.
>   With the iAd Developer App Testing feature you can display and refresh your iAds in seconds and see if it brings any problems to your application. Etc. [Source](http://www.icapps.com/ios-developer-settings/)